# Why do i have to use a for loop and not a foreach loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I hope I'm also allowed to ask questions instead of really having errors and need to fix them.

I got the following code:

```
public boolean equals(NaturalNumberTuple givenTuple) {
    int count = 0;
    if(tuple.length == givenTuple.getLength()){
        for(int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++){
            if(this.tuple[i] == givenTuple.tuple[i]){
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count == tuple.length){
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

So as you can see I'm using a normal for loop but I learned that I can use a so called foreach loop

```
for(int i : tuple){...}
```

but if i try to use it I'm getting an error "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" if I try to check two Arrays for equality.

Can someone explain me why I can't use a foreach loop here?

Comment: Are you aware that in the foreach loop `i` is the actual int, not the index?

Comment: edit: well yeah I forgot that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My only bet is that you wrote:

```
for(int i : tuple){
    if(this.tuple[i] == givenTuple.tuple[i]){
        count++;
    }
}
```

In the for-each loop, `i` takes the value of the element in the array. It's not the index. Let's say you have:

```
int[] arr = {1, 4, -2};
```

`i` will take the value 1, 4 and -2, not 0, 1, 2.

As you need the index to access `givenTuple.tuple[i]`, I think you can stick with the traditionnal for loop, or use `Arrays.equals` (that would be a one-liner).

Oh also note that `public boolean equals(NaturalNumberTuple givenTuple)` is not an override of the `equals` method (which can give you unexpected surprises)

Comment: oooh Well I didn't think about that sorry. :(
So i should @Override at the top of it? 
not allowed to use those methods I have to create my own

Comment: @NhatNienne Yes you would need to do `@Override public boolean equals(Object givenTuple) {` and ensure that `givenTuple` is a `NaturalNumberTuple` instance and that both arrays are equals.